Issue converting moderncv file to html via htlatex
I am trying to convert a moderncv latex file to html using htlatex and am running into an issue. Here is a minimal failing example (fails in htlatex but works fine with pdflatex):
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\name{John}{Doe}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
test & test & test
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}

when I run htlatex on this, I get the error
! Undefined control sequence.
\begin:current@color ->\let \sv:curcolor 
                                         \current@color 
l.8 \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
                            
? 
! Emergency stop.
\begin:current@color ->\let \sv:curcolor 
                                         \current@color 
l.8 \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
                            
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.

The error goes away if I comment out the tabular block. I have tried with the following config file as well but no luck
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble


Is this just a fundamental incompatibility between moderncv and htlatex or am I missing something here?

Edit: I've just added the Moderncv support to TeX4ht sources. It is now possible to compile moderncv documents. The result looks like this:


Original answer:
There is no support for moderncv in TeX4ht. It shouldn't be that hard to create it, if there is a demand for it.
The main problem with your MWE is a clash between code that redefines table handling macros, though. In particular, with the TeX4ht configuration file for the arydshln package. This version of arydshln.4ht fixes the fatal error:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% arydshln.4ht (2022-03-21-13:43), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2022 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2022-03-21-13:43}

% this is a copy of code that arydshln inserts to \@array
\def\:new:array{
         \adl@everyvbox\everyvbox
         \everyvbox{\adl@arrayinit \the\adl@everyvbox \everyvbox\adl@everyvbox}%
         \let\adl@noalign\noalign
}
\ifcsname n:@array:\endcsname% if \@array was already patched by TeX4ht
  \let\orig:n@array\n:@array:
  \def\n:@array:{\:new:array\orig:n@array}
\else
  \pend:def\@array{\:new:array}
\fi
\Hinput{arydshln}
\endinput


This is the result:


thanks, appreciate it!
